# ClassCastException android.view.viewgroup.$layoutParam

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

```
 TextView txt=new TextView(productlist.this);
            txt.setText(author.get(groupPosition));
            TextView txt1=new TextView(productlist.this);
            txt1.setText(price.get(groupPosition));
            txt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(70, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
            txt1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(70,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(productlist.this);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
           // ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);  
            ll.addView(txt);  
            ll.addView(txt1);  

            return ll;
```

hi, this is the code snippet for a group view in expandable `ListView` which gives error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException android.view.viewgroup.$layoutParam

Answer (score 13):

Make sure you import the correct `LayoutParams`.

- android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams for LinearLayout
- android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams for TextView

Comment: I had this same problem, but it only manifested itself when running on old (version 8) devices. Version 17 devices didn't complain even though I was using the 'wrong' LayoutParams. Thanks, Gallal.